# problem in getAverageRank in method in coursera java course

Tags: java

I am working on assignment in coursera java course. The assignment is about statistics in java they give me some files with number of births for each name and wanted the rank of each name for example hesham 15, ahmed 12 and ibrahim 10 so hesham ranked no 1 and ahmed no 2. Names are put in the file sorted by they rank (CSV file) Hesham M 15 then Ahmed M 12 and so on.Females first followd by females. I worked on getAverage and it works as expected but when I try to use it in a different method it doesn`t give me the expected result please help me with this issue as I am stuck. This is the code of the two methods

```
public int getRank(int year, String name, String gender, FileResource fr) {
    int rank = 0;
    int colNum = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    fr = new FileResource();
    for (CSVRecord record : fr.getCSVParser(false)) {
        if (record.get(0).equals(name) && record.get(1).equals(gender))
            found = true;
    }
    for (CSVRecord record : fr.getCSVParser(false)) {
        colNum++;
    }
    for (CSVRecord record : fr.getCSVParser(false)) {
        rank++;
        if (record.get(0).equals(name) && record.get(1).equals(gender))
            break;
    }
    if (found == true) {
        if (gender.equals("F"))
            return rank;
        else
            return rank = rank - (colNum / 2);
    }
    else
        return -1;
}
```

---

```
double getAverageRank(String name, String gender) {
    double average = 0;
    int rank = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int year = 0;
    String namem = null;
    DirectoryResource dr = new DirectoryResource();
    for (File f : dr.selectedFiles()) {
        FileResource fr = new FileResource(f);
        counter++;
        System.out.println("Counter is " + counter);
        name = f.getName();
        System.out.println("name of file  is " + name);
        int index = name.indexOf("yob", 0);
        namem = name.substring(index + 3, index + 7);
        System.out.println("name of year is " + namem);
        year = Integer.parseInt(namem);
        int currrank = getRank(year, name, gender, fr);
        System.out.println("current rank is " + currrank);
        rank = currrank + rank;
        System.out.println("rank final is " + rank);
    }
    return rank / counter;
}
```

Comment: Are you using [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) ?

Comment: Can you add examples of these CSV files to your question?

Comment: where do these class come from? DirectoryResource and FileResource. I don't recognize them as standard java classes

Comment: @Abra yes these are my imports import edu.duke.* ; 
import org.apache.commons.csv.* ; 
import java.io.File;

Comment: @Bentaye I think they are customized class by the university of duke these are my imports import edu.duke.* ; 
import org.apache.commons.csv.* ; 
import java.io.File;

Comment: @Bentaye they are the official files of USA files of births , they are like spread sheet I don`t know how to include file in comments . Sorry this is my first post here and i am new in programming

Comment: @HeshamAdel If they are CSV files, you can open them with the notepad. Open one with the notepad and copy a few lines so we see what they look like.

Comment: @Bentaye Sophia,F,10
Emma,F,9
Isabella,F,8
Olivia,F,7
Ava,F,6
Jacob,M,8
Mason,M,7
Ethan,M,7
Noah,M,6
William,M,5

Comment: @HeshamAdel Are the method signatures given to you? Or can you do whatever you want?

Comment: @Bentaye they are given to us. what i think is challanging is that method get rank alone works perfectly but when i try to use it in the second method it returns -1

Comment: @I am stuck in this bug for 3 days now ,can`t find the answer for it

Comment: @One more question, I assume that each file has a year on their name. Is there a year range? from what year to what year? What is the file name format?

Comment: @Bentaye yob2012short,yob2013short,yob2014short

Comment: when i tried getRank(2012,"Isabella","F",fr) the output is 4 .But in the getAverageRank("Isabella","F") I printed the getRank(name,gender) returned -1

Comment: @HeshamAdel see if my answer works

Comment: @Bentaye where is it

Comment: @HeshamAdel well I posted an answer to your question, so right below

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. :). But get rank method I implemented it like that because the rank for men is different than women. The women's rank starts from the first column say the first five columns are for women then come the film's of men which should start also from first so the first man's name comes in the sixth column which is the first rank thanks again for helping me .

Comment: And the year parameter Willbe used in another method.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 main issues with your implementation:

- You override the name variable with the year, so you are passing the file name to getRank(), not the name you are looking for.
- In getRank you do **fr = new FileResource();** Don't create a new FileResource, use the FileResource you get as parameter

getRank() is lot simpler than you think, this should fix your implementation:

```
// fr holds your file, so all you have to do is:
// - look each line of the file until you find the name and gender
// - return the value of the 3rd column
public int getRank(int year, String name, String gender, FileResource fr) {
    for (CSVRecord record : fr.getCSVParser(false)) {
        if (record.get(0).equals(name) && record.get(1).equals(gender)) {
            return Integer.parseInt(record.get(2));
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

---

```
double getAverageRank(String name, String gender) {
    DirectoryResource dr = new DirectoryResource();

    int rank = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    for (File f : dr.selectedFiles()) {
        FileResource fr = new FileResource(f);

        counter++;
        System.out.println("Counter is " + counter);

        // here do not use the name param to hold the file name, you will lose the name you are looking for
        // instead create a new variable, here fileName 
        String fileName = f.getName();
        System.out.println("name of file  is " + fileName);

        int index = fileName.indexOf("yob", 0);
        String yearAsString = fileName.substring(index + 3, index + 7);
        System.out.println("name of year is " + yearAsString);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(yearAsString);

        int currrank = getRank(year, name, gender, fr);
        System.out.println("Rank in current file is " + currrank);

        rank = currrank + rank;
        System.out.println("Rank total is " + rank);
    }

    int averageRank = rank / counter;
    System.out.println("Average rank = " + averageRank);
    return averageRank;
}
```

**Note:**

getRank() receives the year, but we don't use it, so even though this works, I think this is not really the implementation they are looking for. However, I can't understand the need for getRank to receive both the year and the FileResource, I would think it is one or the other.

We could have

```
public int getRank(String name, String gender, FileResource fr)
```

and it would still work